# Classify list of points as a shape

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a set of ordered 2D points that represent the shape of a mouth.  I would like to create a classifier that can determine if the mouth is "open" or "closed".  Later I will want to add more shapes such as "OOh" and "Eee".

What kind of training algorithm should I use for this kind of classification in python/numpy?

I currently have the data laid out in numpy like this:

```
[ 
  [ [ x1a, x1b ... ], [ y1a, y1b, ...] ]
  [ [ x2a, x2b ... ], [ y2a, y2b, ...] ] 
  ...
]
```

Any pointers appreciated.  I have been using python for a while, but I am fairly new to numpy and very new to machine learning.

Thanks!

[image: Mouth Points Poses]

Comment: You would need a training set of pictures (or representations) of closed and open mouths, otherwise it will be pretty hard to train your system.

Answer (score 1):

There are many acceptable ways to do this. I would personally use Keras (a easy way to use TensorFlow). Note you will have to have a very large data set with labels for this to work.

Comment: How large is large?

Comment: In the image above I had labeled the closed and open mouth shapes - my feeling is that is should be fairly trivial to tell those apart.  What I am more interested in is how to extend this to other shapes and be able to make a reliable switch between them.

Comment: @peeldog: A couple of thousand if you are classifying multiple tags(open closed and the vowels). But if you are just using 2 tags and are okay with an accuracy of 80% then a set of 200 should be plenty.

Comment: One thing I have been considering is rather than using the shape itself, using the offsets from a neutral pose to determine the shape.  So on any given trial a "zero" pose is set, and metrics are the markers in relation to that position, rather than their absolute position in 2d space.  Just a thought,  Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: @peeldog I am attempting this same task in c++. Did you find an approach that works?